# Intellisense mistaking getline as an overloaded function

Tags: c++, getline

Hello :) I am trying to work on a project for my Intro to Programming class and I am running into an issue where intellisense is (mistakenly?) reading my use of getline as an overloaded function. It's probably my own fault, but I wanted to bring it here for an explanation if it is something that I have done.

The project requires me to open the file:

```
// Local variables
int position = 0;

// Open column1.txt
ifstream column1;
column1.open("column1.txt");
```

Now that the file is open, the contents must be read into an array (string COLUMN1[50] is declared as a global variable at the beginning of the code):

```
// Copy its contents into the first array
if (column1.is_open())
{
    while (!column1.eof() && position < 50)
    {
        COLUMN1[position] = getline(column1, position, '/n');
        position++;
    }
}
```

So that's it. I'll include the entire code below for reference. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

// Funtion Prototypes
void copyCat();             // File that copies the info to the arrays

// Global Constants
const string COLUMN1[50];   // Each of the columns of
const string COLUMN2[50];   // insults. Each column is
const string COLUMN3[50];   // located in a different file.

// ---------------------------------------------
// Name: Main
// Purpose: Houses the program's main process
// Returns: int 0
// ---------------------------------------------
int main()
{
    copyCat();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

// -----------------------------------------
// Name: copyCat
// Purpose: Copies the files into the arrays
// Returns: void
// -----------------------------------------
void copyCat()
{
    // Local Variables
    int position = 0;

    // Open column1.txt and copy it into the array
    ifstream column1;
    column1.open("column1.txt");

    // Copy its contents into the first array
    if (column1.is_open())
    {
        while (!column1.eof() && position < 50)
        {
            COLUMN1[position] = getline(column1, position, '/n');
            position++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't look like it would compile, does it? Look at the documentation of the getline function.

Comment: Well.. Because [std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) **is** overloaded. It's just.. none of the overloads take `int` as a second argument.

Comment: `.eof()` as loop condition is wrong. Use `.good()` instead.